# Schema.org Menu type property hasMenuSection & hasMenuItem

Tags: html, schema.org

I'm trying to create an menu in schema.org, but somehow it's not coming up valid. This has to do with the properties hasMenuSection & hasMenuItem. What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Menu" itemref="restaurant-info-footer">
<meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="<?php echo get_locale(); ?>">
<h2 itemprop="name"><?php echo get_the_title( $menu_id ); ?></h2>

<?php if ( ! empty( $menu_price ) && ! is_null( $menu_price ) && $hide_prices ) : ?>
    <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo number_format( $menu_price, 2, ',', '.'); ?>">
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="courses" itemscope itemprop="hasMenuSection" itemtype="http://schema.org/hasMenuSection">
    <?php foreach ( $courses as $course ) : ?>
        <div class="course" itemscope itemprop="MenuSection" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuSection">
            <div class="course-holder" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $course['image']; ?>);">
                <h3 itemprop="name"><?php echo $course['name']; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="course-dishes" itemscope itemprop="hasMenuItem" itemtype="http://schema.org/hasMenuItem">
                <?php foreach ( $course['dishes'] as $dish ) : ?>
                    <?php $dish = $dish['dish']; ?>
                    <div class="dish" itemscope itemprop="MenuItem" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuItem">
                        <h4 itemprop="name"><?php echo get_the_title( $dish ); ?></h4>
                        <?php if ( ! empty( get_field( 'more-price', $dish ) ) && ! is_null( get_field( 'more-price', $dish ) ) && ! $hide_prices ) : ?>
                            <span class="more-price">(<?php _e( 'addition', 'croy-plugin' ); ?> <?php the_field( 'more-price', $dish ); ?>)</span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ( get_field( 'vegan', $dish ) ) : ?>
                            <span class="vegan" itemprop="suitableForDiet" content="http://schema.org/VeganDiet"></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <p itemprop="description"><?php the_field( 'subtitel', $dish ); ?></p>
                        <?php if ( ! empty( get_field( 'price', $dish ) ) && ! is_null( get_field( 'price', $dish ) ) && ! $hide_prices ) : ?>
                            <div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers" itemscope>
                                <p itemprop="price"><?php echo number_format( get_field( 'price', $dish ), 2, ',', '.' ); ?></p>
                                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The debugger tells the following errors:

> hasMenuSection is not a valid target type for the property hasMenuSection.
>
> hasMenuItem is not a valid target type for the property hasMenuItem.

While Offers and MenuItem are good.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hasMenuSection](https://schema.org/hasMenuSection) is a property, not a type. Therefore the following code where you're setting itemscope twice, once for hasMenuSection (which isn't a type) and one for MenuSection which isn't a property, is incorrect.

> ```html
> <div class="courses" itemscope itemprop="hasMenuSection" itemtype="http://schema.org/hasMenuSection">
>     <?php foreach ( $courses as $course ) : ?>
>         <div class="course" itemscope itemprop="MenuSection" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuSection">
> ```

The code should be as follows. `itemscope` is used once to declare a new scope. `itemprop` refers to the property name. `itemtype` refers to the type contained within.

```html
<div class="courses">
    <?php foreach ( $courses as $course ) : ?>
        <div class="course" itemscope itemprop="hasMenuSection" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuSection">
```

The same applies to [hasMenuItem](https://schema.org/hasMenuItem)

> ```html
> <div class="course-dishes" itemscope itemprop="hasMenuItem" itemtype="http://schema.org/hasMenuItem">
>     <?php foreach ( $course['dishes'] as $dish ) : ?>
>         <?php $dish = $dish['dish']; ?>
>         <div class="dish" itemscope itemprop="MenuItem" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuItem">
> ```

should be

```html
<div class="course-dishes">
    <?php foreach ( $course['dishes'] as $dish ) : ?>
        <?php $dish = $dish['dish']; ?>
        <div class="dish" itemscope itemprop="hasMenuItem" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuItem">
```

A related error later is caused by a similar mistake.

> ```html
> <div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers" itemscope>
> ```

offers is not a type, it's the property. `itemprop="offers"` is correct in declaring a property, but itemtype should be [Offer](https://schema.org/Offer), not offers which doesn't exist. The above will get you the following error:

> offers is not a known valid target type for the offers property.

Therefore it should be

```html
<div class="price" itemscope itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
```